# Laravel 4, complicated IF SQL selection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

hope you can help.
I'm working with Laravel 4, MySQL and of course PHP.

**Table:** msg

**Fields:** content, sender, reciever, sender_deleted, reciever_deleted.

I'm trying to get the following converted to SQL:

```
*Retrieve all where you are the sender, if sender_deleted == 0, and where you are the receiver, if reciever_deleted == 0.*
```

Essentially I want all msg, if you are sender or reciever, and you have not deleted that message.

I'm absolutely stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: You want all messages a user has sent to themselves, or messages you've both sent (to anyone) and received? The difference is an OR instead of an AND in your pseudo-sql. Also, are sender and receiver user IDs?

Comment: Ty. sender/reciever are usernames. I might add userid for later but not needed right now. I want ALL messages, sent and recieved for a user. To anyone, but not yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this (In your `Message` model)

```
public static function getMessages($user)
{
    $messages = DB::table('msg')
                ->where('sender', $user)
                ->where('sender_deleted', 0)
                ->orWhere('receiver', $user)
                ->where('reciever_deleted', 0)
                ->get();
                return $messages;
}
```

From your controller, you can then call and pass to the view

```
$messages = Message::getMessages($userid);
return View::make('message')->with('messages', $messages);
```